# Taking Quizbowl buzzers and connecting to a computer

Tags: usb, adapter, configuration, rca

Recently I Bought quizbowl buzzers from buzzersystems.com and the buzzers i received use an rca cable.

[image: Here is an image of the cable depicted]

If you did not know basically, when you click a button, it sends a signal to a box which receives it and lights up/makes a sound.

[image: Button used to input signal]

Is there anyway that I can somehow connect this to my computer so that every time I click the button, it sends the signal of the enter key on my keyboard? Preferentially something that uses usb to reconfigure the signal.

Sepcs 
22AWG, uL2464#22x2c cord
Normally open, momentary push-to-close switch
0.050 ohm (max when new, measured at button) 
* AC specs (current and voltage): 3A @ 125 VAC 1.5A @ 250 VAC (250VAC is max AC voltage) 
* DC specs (current and voltage): 24 VDC (max),10A (max) Note: LOW DC VOLTAGE!

Anyone know if this is equivalant to what type of normal rca cable? Audio, video,mono or dual channel etc.

Comment: the button is most likely only a switch .... it does not generate a signal, but it connects the two connections together

Comment: the reason i think it is a switch is because after you click the button, the signal remains and a light, lights up. And this light stays on until you click another button which is a reset button.

Comment: i was not very clear .... i meant to say that it is only a switch, there are no other electronic components inside the handle .... that means that you can use the device anyplace where you have a pushbutton switch

Comment: I do not wish to strip the end of the wire and get rid of the rca cable. Can i just have an rca to usb adapter and program it?

Comment: If this is just a switch and cable, any USB device expecting audio on an RCA connector will not do anything when you press the button.  Just because the thing happens to use an RCA connector does not mean it carries audio or video information.  You can use a female RCA connector to connect to the switch - no need to cut the existing connector off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there anyway that I can somehow connect this to my computer so that every time I click the button, it sends the signal of the enter key on my keyboard? Preferentially something that uses usb to reconfigure the signal.

Yes you can do both.

Find a secondhand USB keyboard. This shouldn't cost you anything. Open it up and removed the keyboard controller PCB.

[image]

*Figure 1. (1) The PCB and contacts. (2) and (3) the matrix keyboard which you'll be dumping.*

- Examine the keyboard matrix before you dump it and see if you can find which contacts are the 'rows' and 'columns'.
- Plug in the keyboard.
- Go to http://www.keyboardtester.com/.
- Using a wire select a row and jumper it to each column in turn while monitoring the online keyboard tester. If you don't find the Enter key on the first row then repeat the procedure for the next row, etc.
- Connect the two Enter terminals to a phono socket and then you can plug in your original controller without modification.

I used the controller in the photo and the contacts were covered with some kind of coating which wouldn't take solder. It scraped off quite easily and I soldered the wires on.

I developed this technique to make a foot-operated switchboard for controlling a slide show while playing the guitar. I stopped testing when I found the combinations I wanted.

*Table 1. The Lenovo keyboard matrix.*

[image]

You could wire several of these controllers to send the key signals '1', '2', '3', etc., to a program or even to WordPad set to a very large font. You would see the keypress sequence on the screen as '213' or similar but if someone holds down the button you might get '21111113'.

Comment: is there anyway i can connect the wire directly without having to strip and cut of the rca male end? Should i buy a female end to usb and cut that up/ strip it?

Comment: just found out the specs of the wire. it is a 22AWG, uL2464#22x2c cord and Normally open, momentary push-to-close
* 0.050 ohm (max when new, measured at button)

* AC specs (current and voltage):
    3A @ 125 VAC
    1.5A @ 250 VAC (250VAC is max AC voltage)

* DC specs (current and voltage):
    24 VDC (max),10A (max) 
    Note: LOW DC VOLTAGE!

Comment: "Is there anyway i can connect the wire directly without having to strip and cut of the rca male end?" I already gave a solution to that problem in my answer. Read it carefully.

Comment: what type of phono socket should i find or does it not matter as long as i connect the wires right?

Comment: @Victor: You need to think a little more before posting. An RCA socket is just a pair of metal contacts so the type doesn't matter. You have said that the switch is just a plain switch - again a pair of metal contacts. There is nothing to go wrong.